# Coin change algorithm: why add 1?

Tags: dynamic-programming

I am referring to the [algorithm](http://www.ideserve.co.in/learn/minimum-number-of-coins-to-make-change) of coin change problem. I am not able to understand the recursive formula `minCoins(sum) = min(minCoins(sum-values[i])) + 1`. Why should we add 1? That part is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each recursive step adds one coin. That one coin is the +1.